# (window as any).global = window;

Tags: angular, typescript, csrf-protection, polyfills

I am new in typescript, and I have used on global var in polyfill.js

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

So with security or XSS purpose is it vulnerable to use. Or should I remove to find another route?
*Thanks, techies.*

Comment: Why would set the value of `window` to `window.global` ? What is the purpose of this ?

Comment: Some libraries depend on this `global`. It's a common polyfill that I believe was even included by default in Angular 5, but no longer in 6.

Comment: Yes @IngoBürk you are correct I have done the same to add in the polyfills.js  file.

Answer (score 10):

Given that `global` is set to the same value as `window` and `window` is still available if you remove `global` - `global` provides no additional means for XSS / security issues than is already available from `window` itself.

So if your question is whether `(window as any).global = window;` creates some new opportunity for a cross-site scripting attack; it doesn't.